# Why I need to add '/' to routerLink but we do not have '/' in router definination?

Tags: angular, router

I am following [angular official tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5). This question confused me, but this tutorial did not explain why so.

When we click a  element, we route to a view/template. You can see, we have '/heroes', why we need to add '/' in here? I removed the '/', then the router cannot work.

```
template: `
   <h1>{{title}}</h1>
   <nav>
     <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
     <a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a>
   </nav>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Here is the router definition, but it does not have '/'.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'heroes',     component: HeroesComponent }
];
```

Comment: To clarify: You're asking why you've to write `/heroes` instead of `heroes`?

Comment: Yes. Why '/heroes' in routerLink?

Comment: because just `'heros'` would be relative to the current route `'/heros'` is relative to the root of app

Comment: @0mpurdy Why we do not add '/' in here? { path: 'heroes',     component: HeroesComponent }

Comment: because you are describing a list of paths that are all relative

Comment: @CodeContributor Just see my post. You don't add a `/` because you're specifiying absolute routes, relative to your root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using `<a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a>` Angular would try to route to `yoururl/heroes`. Using `<a routerLink="heroes">Heroes</a>` instead appends the link to your current route.

Let's say e.g. you're on this route `yoururl/dasboard`.

This would basically navigate to `yoururl/heroes`

`<a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a>`

While this would navigate to `yoururl/dasboard/heroes`

`<a routerLink="heroes">Heroes</a>`

Comment: This one <a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a> routers to yoururl/heroes

Comment: Seems like I've got it wrong though. In this case it should be the exact oposite of what I've wrote. I'll just edit accordingly. But anyways the attempt I've tried to explain should still be correct. It's just about relative path routing.

Comment: Thanks. After more users upvotes your answer. I will accept your answer, because I do not have an ability to check if your explanation is correct or not.  I appreciate.